# SQL - Find most recent value from other fields (per user, between occurrences)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have actions and results mixed together in an "event" field. But each of these actions essentially "causes" the result (and the subsequent outcome) (let's assume). I want to tie each future outcome back to the actions that caused it, for each user.

I want the value from the "outcome" field to be copied into a new field for each user's most upcoming, future result (if a result has occurred after that action). And I want to record the time of that result/outcome. So for example, if user_1 does three events then has a good outcome, I want the word "good" in a new field for each of those three preceding events. If user_2 has 2 actions, then a bad outcome, then 3 actions: I want the 2 first actions to have "bad" and the last 3 actions to have "?" in the event_outcome field.

*Note: event_timestamp field does not always come chronologically (with relation to row number). I've shown it ordered this way to make it easier to understand.

What I have is this*

```
event_timestamp             |   user|   event       |   outcome
2020-07-20 15:00:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-throw|   
2020-07-20 15:01:00.000 UTC |   1   |   result      |   good
2020-07-20 15:02:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |   
2020-07-20 15:03:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-run  |   
2020-07-20 15:04:00.000 UTC |   2   |   result      |   bad
2020-07-20 15:05:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-throw|   
2020-07-20 15:06:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |   
2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC |   1   |   result      |   bad
2020-07-20 15:08:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |   
2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC |   2   |   result      |   good
2020-07-20 15:10:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-pull |   
2020-07-20 15:11:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-push |
```

What I want is this

```
event_timestamp             |   user|   event       |   outcome |   event_outcome   |   event_outcome_timestamp
2020-07-20 15:00:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-throw|           |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:01:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:01:00.000 UTC |   1   |   result      |   good    |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:01:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:02:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |           |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:03:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-run  |           |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:04:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:04:00.000 UTC |   2   |   result      |   bad     |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:04:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:05:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-throw|           |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:06:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |           |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC |   1   |   result      |   bad     |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:08:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |           |   ?               |   ?
2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC |   2   |   result      |   good    |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:10:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-pull |           |   ?               |   ?
2020-07-20 15:11:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-push |           |   ?               |   ?
```

I can find the most recent outcome for each user (Ideally I would have "?" instead of null if no outcome is known). with this code:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from table
    where event_timestamp > x
    ) temp1
LEFT JOIN
(select user as user2, outcome as outcome_latest, event_timestamp as event_timestamp_latest_outcome
from(
    select user, event_timestamp, outcome
    row_number() over (partition by user order by UNIXMILLIS(event_timestamp) desc) as rn
    from table
    where event_timestamp > x
    and outcome is not null
    )
where rn = 1
) temp2
on temp1.user = temp2.user2
```

Which yeilds this (NOT what I want)

```
event_timestamp             |   user|   event       |   outcome |   outcome_latest  |   event_timestamp_latest_outcome
2020-07-20 15:00:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-throw|           |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:01:00.000 UTC |   1   |   result      |   good    |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:02:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |           |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:03:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-run  |           |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:04:00.000 UTC |   2   |   result      |   bad     |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:05:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-throw|           |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:06:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |           |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC |   1   |   result      |   bad     |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:08:00.000 UTC |   1   |   action-push |           |   bad             |   2020-07-20 15:07:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC |   2   |   result      |   good    |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:10:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-pull |           |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC
2020-07-20 15:11:00.000 UTC |   2   |   action-push |           |   good            |   2020-07-20 15:09:00.000 UTC
```

But I don't know where to go from here. Maybe another level of nesting "partition by"? Over the event field?...

We are using BigQuery, if that context helps.
Thank you!

Comment: How does the first row get a "good" outcome?  There are no rows with that value up to or including that row.

Comment: The first row gets a "good" event_outcome because the next future outcome for that user (user 1) is "good" (see the second row). In other words, the second row (user 1 at 2020-07-20 15:01 outcome = good) makes all preceding (by timestamp, not row number) rows with user 1 have an event_outcome = good.  Sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i would do it in regular SQL. I am assuming that Big Query supports the analytical functions that i have used.

```
with data
 as (
select *
      ,case when (lag(outcome) over(partition by user1 order by event_timestamp) <> ' '
                  and outcome =' '
                 )/*Check if there has been a change in outcome by user*/
             OR (outcome=' ' 
                 and row_number() over(partition by user1 order by event_timestamp)=1
                )/*for the first record per user, we consider it to be a new group*/
            then
                row_number() over(partition by user1 order by event_timestamp)
            else ' '
        end as grp_val
  from t
     )
    ,computed_grp_val
     as(select *
               ,sum(case when grp_val =' ' then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by user1 order by event_timestamp) as grp_val_1
         from data
        )
select *
      ,case when max(outcome) over(partition by user1,grp_val_1)=' ' then '?'
            else max(outcome) over(partition by user1,grp_val_1)
        end as comptued_outcome
      ,max(event_timestamp) over(partition by user1,grp_val_1) as computed_event_timestamp
  from computed_grp_val
order by 1  



+-----------------------------+-------+--------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------------------------+
|       event_timestamp       | user1 |    event     | outcome | grp_val | grp_val_1 | comptued_outcome |  computed_event_timestamp   |
+-----------------------------+-------+--------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2020-07-20 15:00:00.0000000 |     1 | action-throw |         |       1 |         1 | good             | 2020-07-20 15:01:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:01:00.0000000 |     1 | result       | good    |       0 |         1 | good             | 2020-07-20 15:01:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:02:00.0000000 |     1 | action-push  |         |       3 |         2 | bad              | 2020-07-20 15:07:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:03:00.0000000 |     2 | action-run   |         |       1 |         1 | bad              | 2020-07-20 15:04:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:04:00.0000000 |     2 | result       | bad     |       0 |         1 | bad              | 2020-07-20 15:04:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:05:00.0000000 |     2 | action-throw |         |       3 |         2 | good             | 2020-07-20 15:09:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:06:00.0000000 |     1 | action-push  |         |       0 |         2 | bad              | 2020-07-20 15:07:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:07:00.0000000 |     1 | result       | bad     |       0 |         2 | bad              | 2020-07-20 15:07:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:08:00.0000000 |     1 | action-push  |         |       6 |         3 | ?                | 2020-07-20 15:08:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:09:00.0000000 |     2 | result       | good    |       0 |         2 | good             | 2020-07-20 15:09:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:10:00.0000000 |     2 | action-pull  |         |       5 |         3 | ?                | 2020-07-20 15:11:00.0000000 |
| 2020-07-20 15:11:00.0000000 |     2 | action-push  |         |       0 |         3 | ?                | 2020-07-20 15:11:00.0000000 |
+-----------------------------+-------+--------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------------------------+
```

DB Fiddle Link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e97ebf473ccf3c33d7c6fa62fd14e51b

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you sooo much!

Comment: I haven’t had time to go through it. But as soon as I can get back to my computer I’ll mark this as right. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: Thanks SO much again!!! I had to make a few changes since I was getting some errors with data types. I think BigQuery doesn't like mixing integers and strings or something. OH, and I should have said before: all blanks are actually null (not " "). I changed line 4 from "<> ' '' to "is not null" (and a few more similar changes).

Comment: It absolutely helps! But I'm having trouble getting it working. 
It seems like when there are two outcomes in a row (chronologically) (without any null values in the outcome field), then it runs into an error. It only picks up the most recent/newest outcome. I think maybe another OR statement defining the grp_val would fix this... but I'm not getting anywhere on how.

Comment: Okay, nevermind! I may have gotten it. I added "OR lag(outcome) over(partition by user1 order by event_timestamp) <> outcome", and I think it's working.

Comment: The query looks for patterns in data, where a pattern is defined as "a current blank/null outcome and a previous not blank/not null" record. And also it considers the first blank/null outcome record in the table. After that It then pegs those records by using the row_number() over(partition by user1 order by event_timestamp). Once i get this i fill up the grp_lvl_1 field by saying increment the counter if there is a new pattern else keep it the same. Once the grp_lvl_1  is filled, then i got the groups i need, for which i use max(eventtimestamp/outcome)